# JSF 2.2 é adequado para um HTML e CSS moderno?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Irei desenvolver diversas aplicações web, e na maioria delas, além de receber a documentação com os requisitos, irei receber de um bom web designer, todo o front-end (estático) com HTML, CSS e Javascript, utilizando layouts modernos.

A minha missão será transformar esse front-end estático em uma aplicação java web funcional que atenda aos requisitos, dentre eles, manter o layout do front-end original.

Sabendo que o JSF é uma ferramenta que gera HTML, será que irá atender à todos os meus requisitos? Ou devo procurar uma alternativa que eu tenha mais controle do HTML gerado, como o JSP?

Comment: Você não tem mais controle sobre o html gerado usando JSP do que usando JSF. Pode ter coisa melhor mas JSF vai servir sim. Você só terá que modificar algumas tags no HTML do designer de modo a apontar para as propriedades e métodos dos seus beans. Você pode inclusive ensinar o designer a fazer este link a beans de teste e a usar as tags do JSF quando for o caso em vez de tags html. Um bom desinger pode aprender isso. Já vi alguns que aprenderam, em Java e outras plataformas. Outra opção é você primeiro fazer o backend de cada página ou de cada parte de página e o designer atuar em seguida.

Comment: Bruno, que eu saiba, a versão jsf 2.2 possui suporte a atributos customizados (`Pass-through attributes`) que você pode usa para fazer a configuração usando seu framework javascript ou componentes. Outra forma é escrever seus próprios componentes, onde você controla o comportamento e o markup gerado. Acredito que tudo que você pode fazer com JSP, você faz melhor com o Facelets (posso estar enganado). Além disso JSP é uma tecnologia antiga, além disso o facelets incorpora muito mais vantagens que o jsp. (e.g: UEL).

Comment: Em relação ao JSF em si, não sei se ele é a melhor alternativa, porque a integração dele com frameworks front-end (Angular, KnockoutJS, Ember, React, etc..) é bastante complicada, mas é possível. Outro problema é com relação as bibliotecas de componentes, que possuem muito css e que é necessário sobreescrever, o que dificulta o uso de um framework CSS (Bootstrap, Foundation e etc...). Mas você pode levar em consideração a possibilidade de construção de WebServices em Java EE também.

Comment: Ja fiz um trabalho desse utilizando JSF 1.2 e deu certo. foi um pouco trabalhoso. Você precisa saber bem o que o componente renderiza. nem tente aplicar um framework front-end. para isso sugiro html statico e o java-rs que seria montado sua api.

Comment: @Wakim Os frameworks JS que você descreveu são para facilitar a implementação de single-page applications e nada tem a ver com receber prontas do designer as views em HTML e CSS; do mesmo modo, se as views já vem prontas, nenhuma biblioteca de componentes JSF será utilizada.

Comment: @Caffé, concordo, mas é possível usar esses frameworks sem roteamento, apenas com o Data Bind, Template e etc, o que ja é bem interessante. Eu já cheguei a trabalhar num projeto onde era usado o PrimeFaces e também o KnockoutJS, pra aproveitar várias das funcionalidades do PrimeFaces que agrega ao JSF mas tentando ter um processamento maior no JavaScript pra reduzir a carga no servidor. No final a gente acabou os componentes baseados no PrimeFaces mas com nosso próprio `Renderer` para gerar um markup interagindo com o Knockout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu me peguei com uma pergunta dessas a uns 5 anos atrás, no lançamento do JSF2.1 e escolhi usar o JSF para fazer meus projetos. Foi a pior decisão que tomei, vou tentar expor alguns pontos:

1. "Vou receber de um bom web-designer todo o html, css e javascript...". Se é realmente um bom web-designer ele vai te dar várias páginas com plugins funcionais de jquery. Layouts modernos feitos com algum framework css como bootstrap e html 5. Na minha epóca o JSF não suportava tags html5, na verdade não aceitava nada além das próprias tags, mas agora parece estar melhor. Quando falamos do resto vejo problemas, geralmente todos os componentes do JSF (usei o prime) usam tables e várias estruturas bem arcaicas para gerar um html compatível com todos os browsers. O resultado é que você vai passar mais tempo ajustando o JSF pra fazer algo parecido com o que precisa do que reusando o que o web-designer te deu.
2. "Aplicações modernas..." geralmente demandam várias artimanhas e jquery libs que o designer vai inserir na aplicação e muita comunicação ajax entre as páginas. Neste ponto você começa a ter problemas com JSF na parte de scripts, porque você terá que usar a parte de ajax que ele te dá, e abandonar o q o web-designer tinha previsto. Usar JSON com JSF simplesmente não é natural e quase sempre você vai se pegar escrevendo conversões manualmente.
3. O modelo "component" que o JSF usa não é adequado para aplicações web tradicionais, como aplicações web abertas. Este tipo de modelo consome mais memoria e vai requerer um servidor mais parrudo dependendo do número de acessos que almeja. Para estes tipos de aplicação é melhor usar algo do tipo MVC.

Acho que JSF é útil para criar aplicações tradicionais, do tipo painel admin, etc. Aplicações que fogem do tradicional é melhor usar alguma ferramenta que realmente te de liberdade. Desde então uso JSP apenas como template, até mesmo alguns componentes como select são escritos em puro html. Alguns vão achar isso um retorno à idade das cavernas, eu prefiro pensar que assim o componente é renderizado perfeitamente, sem quebrar nenhum pixel do layout, em dispositivos de todos os tamanhos. E pra mim é isso que importa no final do dia.

Comment: É perfeitamente viável usar HTML5 puro com JSF e inclusive mesclar o uso de ambos na mesma view. Você diz *"todos os componentes do JSF (usei o prime)"* mas se o AP vai receber as views prontas em HTML, CSS e JS, é óbvio que ele não vai usar PrimeFaces. Também não há nenhum problema em usar qualquer JS para fazer requisições AJAX ao servidor JSF, bem como nunca tive nenhuma dificuldade em usar JSON+JSF. Por fim, JSF é MVC. Pena você encontrar tantas dificuldades em fazer um aplicativo moderno usando JSF, mas o AP pode ter mais sorte, como eu tive, e pode postar aqui suas dúvidas específicas.

Comment: @Caffé Compartilho das mesmas dores do Célio. Se o HTML vem pronto,  o JSF seria usado apenas para fazer o *bind* dos campos da tela com o model. Claro que dá para usar HTML puro num facelet e fazer Ajax manual, mas então qual o propósito do JSF? Seria uma complexidade desnecessária. Neste caso, um framework *action based* acaba sendo muito mais vantajoso.

Comment: Aliás, o JSF pode até ser MVC, mas bem diferente de um MVC web tradicional. O modelo *component based* armazena por padrão estado no servidor, escopos de *session* e *view* quebram o modelo *stateless* do HTTP, o modelo de navegação normal, sem redirecionamento, causa diversos problemas de navegação. Claro, dá pra usar *request scope*, armazenar o estado no *client* e redirecionar o usuário após cada chamada. Só que fora os bugs comuns nas implementações do JSF que surgem quando você sai do padrão, no fim das contas são necessárias tantos ajustes que acaba igualzinho a um *action based*.

Comment: @utluiz Não creio que o modelo de navegação sem redirecionamento seja o "normal", apesar de concordar que infelizmente este seja muito utilizado. Também não vejo por que uma view construída por um designer impossibilitaria o uso do Ajax do JSF. Mas também não sei de que designer estamos falando; os designers com os quais tenho trabalhado conhecem a parte do framework que diz respeito ao seu trabalho, sejam tags JSF, Rails, React... e dispõem de ambiente e conhecimento para desenvolver e testar as views. Não existe "html pronto" em um aplicativo web - isso só vai existir em páginas estáticas.

Comment: @utluiz Quanto ao MVC, JSF de fato faz um MVC bem transparente o qual você nem percebe que está usando e do qual você escapa facilmente justamente por não estar preocupado com o conceito. De qualquer modo, a pergunta não requer MVC.

Comment: Vou me ater a teor da conversa.
Tenho mais de 8 anos de experiência trabalhei com JSP (5 anos JSP e Servlets  e trabalho a 3 anos com JSF 1.1, 2.1, e 2.2, ultimo projeto uso botstrap, bibliotecas divesas de js (aqui sempre tem Ajustes), mas o que eu quero dizer é que se você tiver $$ e conhecimento para fazer seu próprio framework faça. mas o primefaces com JSF 2.2 é excelente. Usa o que há de mais moderno em relação a css (herança de classe, complexidade que todas falam, executa e carrega classes css em tempo de execução, se não souber fazer overred  de class css, ai vai penar),

Comment: Quanto ao servidor parrudo é história, meu servidor é de 2GB para SO e o sistema e ainda sobra 300MB, para 100 usuários simultaneos. hoje em dia isso é tão barato, que 2 a 3 horas de serviço compram ou aluga muita memória (ai vai gastar 1000 horas para fazer um framework e mais 20 horas por mês para dar manutenção ao framework), ai precisa colocar na balança, outro sua aplicação precisa e deve ser distribuida se precisar atender um grande numero de usuários, para atender escalabilidade.